# Display Data from JSON that doesn't have a name with Angular JS

Tags: javascript, json, angularjs

The json I'm working with goes something like this:

```
{
 nameofProduct: {
   Alive: {
        ImServer1: {
              status: "low",
              title: "ImServer1"
        },
        ImServer2: {
             status: "high",
             title: "Imserver2"
       },
       ImServer3: {
             status: "medium",
             title: "ImServer3"
       }
```

I'm trying to display the name ImServer1, ImServer2, ImServer3 and their status and title inside.

My angular js. js file looks like this

```
   var app = angular.module("nameofproduct", []);

     app.controller("MainController", function($scope, $http) {
      $scope.loading = true;
      $http.get('https://jsonp.nodejitsu.com/?url=http://jsonp.jit.su/?url=httpfakeurl.com').
      success(function(data, status, headers, config) {
      $scope.Servers = data;
      $scope.loading = false;
      }).
        error(function(data, status, headers, config) {
        console.log(data);
     });
});
```

Currently I have my html set up like this:

```
<body ng-app="nameofproduct">
 <div ng-controller="MainController">
 <div class="col-lg-6" ng-repeat="server in Servers">
        <div class="col-lg-6">{{server.nameofServer.Alive}}   </div>
        <div class="col-lg-1"><i class="{{server.status == 'low' ? 'thumbs-down' : 'humbs-up'}}" style="{{server.status == 'low' ? 'color:red;' : 'color:green;'}}"></i></div>
         <div class="col-lg-5">
                   <span class="badge" ng-class="{'badge-offline': server.status == 'low', 'badge-low': server.status == 'Low', 'badge-medium': server.status == 'medium', 'badge-high': server.status == 'high', 'badge-vhigh': server.status == 'evry high'}">{{server.status}}
                   </span>
         </div>
```

But at the moment is just displays all the data, and doesn't split it apart. I'm not sure what I'm missing and how to proceed.

Comment: You could transform the object to an array in success function like: 
for(int i=0;i<Object.keys(data).length;i++){
   newData.push(Object.keys[i])
} to transform object to an array.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given the json you have, when you do `$scope.Servers = data`, what you're really putting in $scope.servers is products. So your ng-repeat is going to try to loop through nameofProduct and anything else on that level.

So ng-repeat says ok, the first element is nameofProduct. Now I need to print `server.nameofServer.Alive` for that.. which is pretty much everything in the above son.

To loop through the individual servers, you would change your assignment in the controller to

```
$scope.Servers = data.nameofProduct.Alive;
```

To do it if you don't know the nameofProduct when you write the code you could either use a loop, or if it will not be an array but a single product use Object.keys():

```
var productName = Object.keys(data)[0];
$scope.Servers = t[productName].Alive;
```

Answer (score 1):

Currently what you are doing is assigning the data that came from http service directly to `$scope.Servers = data;` which is  not correct.

Take a look at the JSON.

```
{
 nameofProduct: {
  Alive: {
    ImServer1: {
          status: "low",
          title: "ImServer1"
    },
    ImServer2: {
         status: "high",
         title: "Imserver2"
   },
   ImServer3: {
         status: "medium",
         title: "ImServer3"
     }
   }
 }
```

To get the all server name and their sattus you have to use the (.) on the JSON object "nameofProduct" like this:

```
$scope.Servers = $scope.data.nameofProduct.Alive;
```

and then assign it on server property that is on scope object.

Take a look at this fiddle. You would get your answer for sure. I have modified it as per question requirement

http://jsfiddle.net/Satbir/HB7LU/10377/